# Intersection of ideals in $k[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

What is the intersection $$I=(y)\cap (x)\cap (x-y)$$ of ideals in $k[x,y]$, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field? How does one compute intersections of ideals? I realize this is a basic question.

Answer (score 1):

In general one can use Groebner bases and Buchberger's algorithm
to compute intersections of ideals in polynomial rings.

Here $k[x,y]$ is a UFD, so the intersection is pretty obviously
the product $(xy(x-y))$.

Comment: Could you please explain why the fact that $k[x,y]$ is a UFD implies that the intersection is $(xy(y-x))$? Thank you.

Comment: @rpf The elements of $I$ are those polynomials divisible by $x$ and by $y$ and by $x-y$.